# iterate over an array of background colors for chartjs in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-visualization

I'm using Rails to display a Chart.js graph of some data.  My rails controller has an array called `@colors` that I pass to a JavaScript file called `graphs.js.erb` which gets displayed in a view template.  Everything is working fine there, my issue is that I have more data points than I do colors and I want to keep looping over the same `colorsFromServer` array to display however many colors I need for each datapoint.

So currently I'm using 6 colors in an array but I have 9 pieces of data to plot on a chart.  I would like to just loop back to the first element in the `colorsFromServer` array and start pushing those colors into the `color` array.

So ultimately with 9 points of data to plot the colors should be

```
  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
   // keeps looping to get the 3 additional colors 
  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
```

In my Rails controller

```
@colors = [
  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
]
```

Javascript

```
<% colors_json = @colors.to_json.html_safe %>
var colorsFromServer = <%= colors_json %>;
console.log("colorsFromServer");
console.log(colorsFromServer);

var colors = [];
var color;
for (var i = 0; i < article_data.length; i++) {
  color = colorsFromServer[i];
  colors.push(color);
}
console.log("COLORS");
console.log(colors);
```

the `colors` variable is what I'm using in Chart.js to draw the graph with certain background colors.  using  the developer tools in Chrome you can see how the last 3 are undefined because the 6 colors have been already used, so I need a way to get back to the start of the colorsFromServer array to push more colors.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to keep up with the color index separately from the data index.
then reset to zero if it is greater than the number of colors available.

```
var colorsFromServer = <%= colors_json %>;
var colors = [];
var color;
var colorIndex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < article_data.length; i++) {
  if (colorIndex >= colorsFromServer.length) {
    colorIndex = 0;
  }
  color = colorsFromServer[colorIndex];
  colorIndex++;
  colors.push(color);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this, so you take the rest from integer division on the length of your array, it will never ecxeed the length.

```
for (var i = 0; i < article_data.length; i++) {
  color = colorsFromServer[i % colorsFromServer.length];
  colors.push(color);
}
```